# Creating a Group to add my Class to in Pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite

I am currently making a game in Pygame, and would like to generate several platforms randomly throughout my screen. However, I can't seem to figure out how to create a group so that I can draw several sprites at once. I have tried using `super.__init__(self)` and also replacing `self` with `(*Group)` , yet it isn't working. I also have just tried to add it to a group. How should I make my group and how do I correctly add my sprite to it?
Here is the code (the sprite I want to add in is created here but not drawn):

```
######## basic setup
import pygame, sys, time, random, threading, tkinter, ctypes
from threading import Timer
from pygame.locals import *
from tkinter import *
pygame.init()
WINDOWHEIGHT = 720
WINDOWWIDTH = 1280
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hitman Grandma | vB1.0 (prealpha)')
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
cyan = (0,255,255)
lightgrey = (198,198,198)
windowSurface.fill(lightgrey)
pygame.display.update()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
########## variables
level = 0
touching = False
global x_speed
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
leftallowed = True
rightallowed = True
hgturnright = True
hgjumpallowed = True
########### the grandma d'awesome murder sorts
hgimage = pygame.image.load('hgfinal.png')
hgimage.convert_alpha()
class HG(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y       
    def draw(self):
        windowSurface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
    def move(self):
        self.x += x_speed
        self.y += y_speed
    def topcollide(self,box):
        if not self.rect.colliderect(box.rect):
            global y_speed
            if y_speed < 20:
                y_speed += 1
            elif y_speed == 20:
                y_speed = 20
            print('shhoooo')
        elif self.rect.colliderect(box.rect):
            y_speed = 0
            print('flop')
hg = HG(0,0,hgimage)
########### land and boundary
lands = pygame.image.load('hgland1.png')
floorland = pygame.transform.scale(lands,(1280,50))
sideedge = pygame.Rect(0,0,1,720),pygame.Rect(1279,0,1,720)
topedge = pygame.Rect(0,0,1280,1)
class Floor(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    def draw(self):
        windowSurface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
class Ground(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def draw(self):
        windowSurface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
class Ground(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        super.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x,y))
    def draw(self):
        windowSurface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
floor = Floor(0,670,floorland)
platform1 = Ground((random.randint(0,800)),(random.randint(50,620)),lands)
########### WHILE
while True:
########### background
    windowSurface.fill(lightgrey)
########### hg movement
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_LEFT and hg.x > 0 and leftallowed:
                    x_speed = -4
                    hgturnright = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT and (hg.x + 36) < WINDOWWIDTH and rightallowed:
                    x_speed = 4
                    hgturnright = True
                if event.key == K_UP and hgjumpallowed:
                    y_speed = -17
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                x_speed = 0
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
########### ctrl+q
            if event.key == K_q and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                exit
########### [x]
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                exit
########### drawing and .move()
    floor.draw()
    hg.draw()
    hg.move()
    hg.topcollide(floor)
########### technicals
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)
```

and here is the class I want to use:

```
class Ground(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        super.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x,y))
    def draw(self):
        windowSurface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
platform1 = Ground((random.randint(0,800)),(random.randint(50,620)),lands)
```

Also, here are the two images to use:[image: this is the grandmother][image: here is the land]

Comment: The line `platform1 = Ground((random.randint(0,800)),(random.randint(50,620)),land)` causes a `NameError: name 'land' is not defined`. Please [edit] your question and correct this.

Comment: If you want your `Group` to act like a `pygame.sprite.Group`, you need to make that the base class of your own. and In your class's `__init__()` method the base class method of the same name can be called using `super().__init__(*sprites)`—note the use of parentheses following `super` (as opposed to `super.__init__(*sprites)`).

Comment: How is your `Group` class going to be different from a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)? Perhaps you could/should just use the predefined  `Group` class by creating an instance of one and adding your own `Sprite` instances to it.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial about [sprites and groups](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13). Alternatively, you could append your objects to a list and iterate over this list with a for loop to update and draw the objects.

Comment: Read the linked tutorial and maybe chapter 12 about classes as well.

Comment: Maximosaur: As a beginner, the first place you should look is the documentation (and `pygame`'s even has examples of real code you can look at if you want to see some). When you don't understand something related to Python itself, like derived class, I suggest you learn that first (it has nothing to do with `pygame` specifically or even Python) and then try writing some test code to it out until you have at least some grasp of what it is—all to keep from getting in over-your-head like you seem to be now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classes should inherit from [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), so that they can be put into sprite groups, e.g. `class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):`. Don't forget to call the `__init__` method of the parent class `super().__init__()`. Then create the sprite groups (`all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()`) and the sprite instances and call the `add` method of the groups to add the sprite.

Then you just have to call `all_sprites.update()` and `all_sprites.draw(screen)` in the main loop.

```
from random import randrange

import pygame as pg


class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()  # This group that will contain all sprites.
    # You probably want to add the platforms to a separate
    # group as well, so that you can use it for collision detection.
    platforms = pg.sprite.Group()

    for _ in range(6):  # Create six platforms at random coords.
        platform = Platform(randrange(600), randrange(440), 170, 20)
        platforms.add(platform)
        all_sprites.add(platform)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Have you figured it out or do you still need help? I could open a chat room if you want.