# Python Crash course chapter 13 "Object has no attribute '_sprite__g'" -- Sorry if duplicated.. had a look but couldnt find answer

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, super

I'm creating the Alien invasion game from the python crash course book. Up until this point i managed but now i have come onto this stage and it has broken everything, the game wont even start let alone run up until the last successful attempt. i am getting an error "Alien has no attribute '_sprite__g'"

I have checked that the Alien class is inheriting properly from sprite, and as far as i can tell it is but i am still new to coding. Used super. function to inherit and it worked until this point now im being told it has no attribute.

This is my code (apologies, there is a fair bit).

main file - alien invasion.py

## Alien_invasion.py

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from alien import Alien
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    #Initialize pygame, settings and screen object.

    pygame.init()
    ai_settings=Settings()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    #Make a ship, a group of bullets and a group of aliens.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()

    #Create the fleet of aliens.
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens)




    #Set the background colour.
    bg_colour = (230, 230, 230)


    #Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        bullets.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
        
run_game()
```

Alien.py

```
#Alien.py

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the alien and set its starting position."""
        super(Alien, self).__init__
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        #Load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        #Store the alien's exact position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the alien at it's current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Game functions.py

```
#Game functions.py

import sys

import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien




def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right =True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Fire a bullet if limit is not reached yet. """
    #Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group.
    if len(bullets) <ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)


def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key ==pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events. """
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    #Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    #Redraw all bullets behind ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()
    alien.draw(screen)

def update_bullets(bullets):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
    #Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()

    #Get rid of bullets that have dissapeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <=0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

    #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()

def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens):
    """Create a full fleet of aliens."""
    #Ceate an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
    #Spacing between each alien is equal to one alien qidth.
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))

    #Create the first row of aliens.
    for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
        #Create an alien and place in in the row.
        alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        aliens.add(alien)
```

Up until adding the code for " Create fleet " it was all working fine, i only had a single ship but the game started and displayed and controlled correctly.

There is a couple more files in the project but i didnt as them they did not seem relevant? i havnt been made to make any ajustments to them as per the tutorial.  I can add them if needed though.

** Note - in game functions i did try using "pygame.display.flip()" after create fleet but it seemed not to make a difference.

This is my Traceback error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\visual studios\Python\Learning Python\Python crash course\alien_invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 44, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "D:\visual studios\Python\Learning Python\Python crash course\alien_invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 27, in run_game
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens)
  File "D:\visual studios\Python\Learning Python\Python crash course\alien_invasion\game_functions.py", line 88, in create_fleet
    aliens.add(alien)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 361, in add
    sprite.add_internal(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 163, in add_internal
    self.__g[group] = 0
AttributeError: 'Alien' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full error? In python the error traceback makes it much easier to find where the issue occurred. I can see the error occured within the `sprite` class with its private variable `__g` which narrows it down but sifting through your code will take a lot more time then just seeing the error traceback.

Comment: Please put this in the question not in the comments :)

Comment: Done, thank you. if there is anything else dont hesitate to let me know. Im also new to stack overflow, ive been told its a great resource and community so thought id give it a go.

Comment: This line looks like it is the issue `super(Alien, self).__init__`. Try doing `super().__init__()` instead. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603775/8150685) may help you as well if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: No luck, the traceback error changes to Naming error alien is not defined.

Comment: On what line? Though I think that is better, we just fixed one of several bugs.

Comment: alien_invasion.py line 44 in run_game(), alien invasion.py line 42 in gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets) and game_functions.py line 58 in update_screen.alien.draw(screen)


dont understand how it could fo so wrong copying the book xD

Comment: When you read a traceback the error occurs on only one line (the last lines).  The traceback is giving you the history of the code. The bottom line of the traceback is where the error occurred, all the other information is so you can back track what the program was doing. The reason you may want the traceback is because the error may be caused by something you did but it may not throw the error until later on (such as the original error to your question).

Comment: Should `alien.draw(screen)` be `aliens.draw(screen)`.

Comment: That solved it so it runs, thank you. . I Understand the alien - aliens change. i dont understand why the first bit of super code didn't work though. but Thank you!

Comment: You were passing a class instance to the constructor for Sprite which it was trying to use as a list. Np enjoy SO.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while creating a bullet.py, I guess u have to re-write the super function with python 3 standards:

```
super().__init__()
```